# MacVim symlink points to earlier vim version

Tags: mac, vim, macvim

Using homebrew I installed MacVim 7.3, but when typing "vim" in terminal it points met to 7.2 version that I installed by downloading MacVim from the web. I must have installed it a while ago and set a symlink to vim.

Cannot figure out how to change that symlink to point to vim 7.3 instead of 7.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more a workaround than a real solution but you could add an alias to your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` pointing to the newest Vim:

```
alias vim='/path/to/new/vim'
```

But the real solution is to search your path (with Finder.app or on the command line) for older versions of Vim.

The older MacVim will probably be in `/Applications` or `~/Applications`, start by deleting it.

I see no good reason for having a symlink pointing to MacVim's vim but if you have made one a simple search would find it quickly.

Comment: Had no affect. Still points to old vim. If I type-in alias in terminal it recognizes the new path, but forgets it each time I open new session. I have removed the older vim version from /Applications folder. As you point out it is more of a superuser question, but I am no expert in Mac. Anyway I would love to figure out how to solve the problem.

Comment: Remove all the `alias vim=` and type `which vim`, what does it say?

Comment: What is the output of `$ sudo find / -name vim`? (I don't think `sudo` is really mandatory since `find` does nothing to files and directories but some of the bundles in my `/Applications` folder have bizarre authorization settings)

Comment: Thanks for involvement, really appreciate it. 

sudo find returned multiple matches, but here is what I did before that. 

Removed `/usr/bin/vim` and my vim command was not recognized anymore. 
If I add in terminal (btw I used iTerm2) window alias I can use vim command:

    `alias vim="mvim -v"`
    `vim open_some_file`

If I modify `~/.bashrc` or/and `~/.profile` by one of these combination, vim command is not recognized:

    `alias vim="/Applications/MacVim-7_3-53/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim"`
    `alias vim="mvim -v"`

Comment: Then I tried creating link, and it does recognize vim command, but then it fails to load `.vimrc` settings and complains about missing colors:

    `sudo ln -s /Applications/MacVim-7_3-53/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim /usr/bin/vim` 

My only goal was to use `"vim"` command instead of typing `"mvim -v"`. You mentioned that symlink to MacVim is not a good idea. Obviously I am missing some basic concepts here and would be glad if you could enlighten me.

Comment: It seems to me that you have a few problems with your configuration. A symlink seems overkill to me since a simple `alias vim="/path/to/recent/vim"` is usually enough to launch `vim somefile`.  For example, I have this line in `~/.profile`: `alias vim='~/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim'` which gives me a perfect `vim` with all the features (exactly the same as in MacVim) I need without messing around with Homebrew or MacPorts. Do your terminal recognises other aliases? What is the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: You are absolutely right, I am messing around with Homebrew, MacPorts and this messed up my configs. But it is part of the learning process and thanks for the help. I solved the issue, by modifying `~/.bash_profile` and adding alias there. I had added rvm script there previously. So many locations, do you know what is the meaning and how do `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc` differ?

Comment: These files are read in a specific order, see `$ man bash` for the exact order. I don't use `~/.bash_profile` at all, I've only used `~/.profile` for years but it gave me a few troubles with `$PATH` when I switched to Vim. Now I have `source ~/.profile` as the only content of `~/.bashrc` and everything is cool.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you install `mvim`, and the symlink? It might be `/usr/local/bin/`. This case I think it is possibly because the old `/usr/bin/vim` goes before the location in `PATH`. You can find out which will be call when you run vim by `which vim`, or try to rename stock vim by rename it to something like `vim72`.
If that works then you can rename it back and try to set `/usr/local/bin/` goes before `/usr/bin` in the `PATH`

Comment: Yes, the `/usr/bin` is indeed before `/usr/local/bin`. But I solved the issue by adding alias to `~/.bash_profile`. Would you still recommend putting `/usr/bin` before `/usr/local/bin` or normally that should not matter?

Comment: You should put the path that leads to the most recent version of Vim before the older one since your shell will launch the first it finds. You can put other exotic paths there too. Like `~/Applications`for example.

Comment: Yes I still recommend putting all your custom paths before OS's ones. This is useful when you're using your dotfiles in different OSes. Setting the PATH right will works for Linux and Mac OS X, while aliasing only works for Mac OS X (It breaks even when you install MacVim in a different place!).